# Identify location of old paintings - WWII soldier

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, history

Does anyone know where the location on this old paintings may be? My great uncle was a doctor in WWII and was given a book half full of paintings by a soldier that he cared for. Unfortunately that’s really all the info we have. The paintings are so beautiful and it would be interesting to find out more.

[image]

Answer (score 26):

This might be the ["White Tower" of Thessaloniki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Tower_of_Thessaloniki), Greece:

[image]

<sup>Anonymous photographer, Public domain, via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:White_tower_1912.jpg)</sup>

[image]

[image]

<sup>Destinygreece, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lefkos_pyrgos_1.jpg)</sup>

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: I agree. The surrounding lower buildings are all gone and the tower is more squat than in the painting, but it can't really be anything else.  According to my cousin (who lives in Thessaloniki) most of the surrounding buildings got demolished in the 60/70's when the city centre got a modern re-vamp.